# Why won't my React Native app run on my device

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, terminal, expo

I want to be able to test my app on `Expo` (an IPhone app used to test React Native code after you hit save) and I just can't seem to get past this error I'm getting `Terminal`.  I've ran my app using `Expo` before with no problems but now after trying to include a Navigator in my app, I get an error.

First I did this:

```
$ npm i -g create-react-native-app
$ create-react-native-app my-project
$ cd my-project`
```

Then I wanted to include a Navigator in my app so I went ahead and did this:

`npm install --save react-navigation`

After that, in order to get `Expo` running I did:

`npm start`

When I do `npm start`, I get this error in `Terminal`:

```
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! Mestro@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Mestro@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: is `react-native-scripts` installed?

Comment: @vijayst I don't think so.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `npm i react-native-scripts`

Comment: @vijayst k, I'll try that and tell you what happens.

Comment: @vijayst Ok so I did  `npm i react-native-scripts` and it worked.  Then I did  `npm start` and threw me an error again.

Comment: @vijayst It's saying something about `react-native-scripts start` in the error.  Is it possible to run something like `npm react-native-scripts start` or something?

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be that you are using npm5, I would recommend using npm4, npm5 is currently (as of june 17, 2017) very buggy. [see this recommendation in the README](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#installation).